# Problems viewing domain.com from local LAN in split-horizon 10.6 OS X Server

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, mac-osx-server, internal-dns, osx-snow-leopard

Having a weird DNS issue. I've had a split-horizon system on my 10.6 OS X Server setup for sometime; this server runs Open Directory and hosts our website. But recently, seemingly after the 10.6.8 update, many machines are unable to view the companyname.net website from within the LAN. It sees to only be 10.7 and iOS devices, as our lone 10.6 machine works.

I can't ping companyname.net from the affected machines, but I can ping www.companyname.net. If I manually enter the IP address into my /etc/hosts file, I can view the site properly. Tried many cache refreshes, HUP clears, etc, but for whatever reason, it seems that my machines are just not picking up the DNS information about the raw companyname.net URL. Quite flummoxed!

Here's my zone file.

```
$TTL 10800
companyname.net. IN SOA macpro.companyname.net. admin.companyname.net. (
        2011090923      ;Serial
        86400           ;Refresh
        3600            ;Retry
        604800          ;Expire
        345600          ;Negative caching TTL
 )

companyname.net. IN  NS macpro.companyname.net.
lion IN  A 10.0.1.3
macpro IN  A 10.0.1.2
companyname.net. IN  CNAME macpro.companyname.net.
ichat IN  CNAME macpro.companyname.net.
mail IN  CNAME macpro.companyname.net.
www IN  CNAME macpro.companyname.net.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I'm surprised this works at all -- the having an alias (CNAME) and other records for the same domain (companyname.net.) is illegal (see [RFC 1912](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt) section 2.4). You should remove this CNAME record and replace it with an A record:

```
$TTL 10800
companyname.net. IN SOA macpro.companyname.net. admin.companyname.net. (
        2011090923      ;Serial
        86400           ;Refresh
        3600            ;Retry
        604800          ;Expire
        345600          ;Negative caching TTL
 )

companyname.net. IN  NS macpro.companyname.net.
lion IN  A 10.0.1.3
macpro IN  A 10.0.1.2
companyname.net. IN  A 10.0.1.2
ichat IN  CNAME macpro.companyname.net.
mail IN  CNAME macpro.companyname.net.
www IN  CNAME macpro.companyname.net.
```

(Note that the reverse entry for 10.0.1.2 should still be a PTR to macpro.companyname.net.)

Comment: I tried that, but then sudo changeip -checkhostname reports a mismatch `Current HostName    = macpro.companyname.net
DNS HostName        = companyname.net`. That not sure if that will cause problems with Open Directory, as the OD Master is running off of the same server. It seems as if it assumed the new entry is the correct one, not the existing A record.

Comment: Check the reverse record -- when you create 2 A records pointing to the same address, Server Admin will pick one semirandomly to base the reverse record on.  You need to go into the reverse record in the 1.0.10.in-addr.arpa zone, and choose "macpro.companyname.net" as the one to use.

Comment: That looks like the piece I've been missing - thanks for the help!